# Why does the broiler of my Frigidaire induction range trip my GFI breaker, on ground fault, after 6-8 minutes?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, kitchens, gfi

With my Frigidaire induction range, new in 2021, the broiler tripped the Siemens 40A, 2-pole, 240V GFI breaker after the broiler operated for 6-8 minutes. No other mode of operation – with burners and/or oven, even with much higher amperage – tripped the breaker.

1. My induction range is a Frigidaire model FGIH3047VFB, purchased new in 2021. To fix the breaker trips when operating in broiler mode, Frigidaire replaced the broiler element and oven relay board under warranty. No change in the tripping.
2. For the heck of it, I removed/re-installed the breaker and wiring connections in my panel. The tripping problem stopped – for about a year. When the tripping started again, it was the same. Broiler operates OK for 6-8 minutes, then trips the breaker. Occasionally, when I turn off the broiler after just a few minutes, the breaker trips simultaneously.
3. I have replaced the breaker with a non-GFI breaker (temporary) and with a second brand-new GFI breaker. The tripping stopped with the non-GFI breaker but started again with the new GFI breaker. So the fault is a ground fault.
4. The data sheet for my range shows that the broiler element operates during Bake, Convection and Clean modes, as well during Broil mode. We have operated the range in all these modes and the breaker trips only in Broil mode, never in any other mode.

So, the question is: What is unique to Broil mode that is causing the ground fault? The only difference I can see is that Broil mode involves pressing the Broil touchpad button of the front control panel (instead of pressing Bake, or Clean, or whatever). Is it possible that a fault produced by the Broil button in the control panel touchpad could trip the breaker on ground fault?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It seems they did not replace the part/s that are causing the problem.  Did they replace any wires/parts between the broiler and board?  Did they do any tests or just replace a couple of parts to see if that fixed the problem/

Comment: Don't know specifically what wiring tests the service rep did. I personally inspected the wiring in the rear and saw no fault, e.g. worn insulation. If there were such a fault, I think the broiler would trip the breaker in Bake, Clean and Convection modes as well as Broiler mode. I have not looked at the wiring to the front control panel.

Comment: What make/product line is the GFCI breaker in question?  Can you get access to a leakage clampmeter for that matter? (Note that it needs to be a *leakage* type -- regular clampmeters are not nearly sensitive enough to measure single digit milliampere currents)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Breaker is Siemens GFCI 2-pole/240V/40A/Cat. No. QF240A. I have clamp ammeters but not a leakage type, since they run $900 or more. I may be able to get one, though.

Comment: If it was a matter of tripping when that element got hot, I'd say thermal expansion was revealing a fault in the wiring to that element. That's not completely ruled out with it being about the mode, but made much less likely. Does it do it every time? How repeatable is the delay? What happens if you run it for 5 minutes, turn it off, then back on again for 5 minutes, etc? This will get it hot while avoiding anything that happens after a 6+ minute timer. Does it have an indicator for when preheating is finished, and if so what does that do?

Comment: Chris, Broiler-only mode always trips the breaker after 7-8 minutes. There's no preheat. My next step is to borrow/rent a current leakage ammeter so I can test for the very low mA currents that trip the breaker on ground fault. It's frustrating that GFI devices are required by code for so many circuits and that the instrumentation to test for the faults is so expensive.

Comment: I finally acquired a current leakage meter that doesn't bankrupt me. I did leakage measurements of the range with all other circuits off. I believe the GFCI breaker is tripping on cumulative leakage currents, exceeding the breaker's limit of 5 mA. The baseline leakage current for my range is 2.75 mA, when the unit is plugged in. I saw 4.54 mA peak during broiler operation, before the trip. I traced 2.5 mA of the baseline leakage to the burner/control panel area. Will continue tracing tomorrow.